# Coredata: How to use alternatively 2 persistent stores with one persistent store coordinator?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspersistentstore

**The setup:**
My app uses uses either own data (own state) or data shared by another user (shared state), and it is possible to switch between both states.
The app uses Coredata with CloudKit mirroring: Own data are stored in the private database, and shared data in the shared database. Both databases are synchronized automatically to two persistent stores, private and shared, coordinated by a single persistent store coordinator.
If in own state, data should be fetched from the private store and stored only there.
Alternatively, in shared state, data should be fetched from the shared store and stored only there.
It is now possible to fetch data only from specific stores by setting the `affectedStores` property of a fetch request appropriately.
But apparently it is not possible to set affected stores for saving changes of a managed object context.

**The question:**
How can I achieve that managed object changes are only saved to one of the persistent stores?

**My ideas:**

- It is possible to add and remove persistent stores from a persistent store coordinator, but this seems to me elaborate. Is there a simpler way to direct saves to specific persistent stores, as it is possible for fetch requests?
- Is it better to use 2 persistent store coordinators, each one coordinating only one persistent store?

Comment: It feels easier with 2 persistent store coordinators, unless your states need to interact and stay consistent with each other. Do they need to interact in some way?

Comment: @battlmonstr No, both states are independent.

Comment: The coordinator is a "pipe" that serializes requests (a point ensuring consistency). If the states are independent, using separate containers/coordinators seems reasonable.
Nevertheless, it would be interesting to know if it is possible to route the updates, and understand what happens there. (is it saved in both stores by default?)

Comment: Since the data model is the same for private and shared data, data updates are currently saved to both persistent stores, and I don't see a way to avoid it with 1 coordinator (except from removing/adding stores). I am using a single coordinator since its viewContext is monitored by a fetched results controller to display the content. With 2 coordinators, this also seems to become elaborate.

Comment: Do you want to display the data in the same UI? (is it at least separate views?)

Comment: Yes, the user first uses and displays by a FRC own data as a tableView, then decides to use and display shared data by replacing own data by the shared data in the tableView, and may later switch back to own data. This should all be handled by the same FRC.

Comment: Yeah, I see. So with 2 PC approach you'd have to refactor the UI to not rely on a single FRC, and have a switching logic (or create 2 FRC instances).

Comment: I just found by chance a solution to my problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258142/1987726) under „Update“. It is possible to tell a managed object context to assign all newly inserted objects a persistent store to which they are saved, see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign). Thus, I can reset the relevant context, and use `assign(_:to:)` to direct saves to the specific persistent store. Anyway, you helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found by chance a solution to my problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258142/1987726) under „Update“:
It is possible to tell a managed object context to assign all newly inserted objects a persistent store to which they are saved, see the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign).
Thus, I can reset the relevant context, and use `assign(_:to:)` to direct saves to the specific persistent store.